# Close MSSQL connection using mssql in node.js

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js

I am trying to write a script in node.js to query a MSSQL database. I am new to javascript, new to node.js, new to VSCode, but I know a few things about SQL. I have working code, but the connection never seems to close, and I cannot get the values OUT of the function.

SO, I have this chunk of code, which I got from the example from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql):

```
const sql = require('mssql');
var dbConfig = {
    server:'theServer',
    database:'theDB',
    user:'un',
    password:'pw',
    port:1433
};

sql.connect(dbConfig).then(pool => {
    // Query     
    return pool.request()
    .query('select top 10 * from THE_TABLE')
}).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    // ... error checks
})
```

This works, and I can see the 10 results get logged in the console. However, the code never stops running. How do I get the connection to close up and stop?

I really want the results to be saved into a variable, so I changed the code to this:

```
const sql = require('mssql');
var dbConfig = {
    server:'theServer',
    database:'theDB',
    user:'un',
    password:'pw',
    port:1433
};

let theList;
sql.connect(dbConfig).then(pool => {
    // Query     
    return pool.request()
    .query('select top 10 * from THE_TABLE')
}).then(result => {
    theList= result;
}).catch(err => {
    // ... error checks
})

console.log(theList);
```

This returns 'undefined' to the console for theList, and again the connection never seems to cose, and the script never shuts down.

How do I just grab the results of the query and move on down the road??

Comment: If my answer was useful to you, you can accept it or qualify it so other users with a similar problem can find a solution faster.

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me. There is a `.close()` method.

```
const DB = require("mssql")
const config = require("./config.json")
DB.connect(config)
   .then((conn) => 
      conn.query("SELECT * FROM table1")
         .then((v) => console.log(v))
         .then(() => conn.close())
   )
```

Answer (score 2):

### Using Async / Await

Here's how to open a connection, query, and close using async await

```js
const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8')

let config = {
    driver: "msnodesqlv8",
    server: serverName,
    database: databaseName,
    options: { trustedConnection: true }
};

// connect to db
let cnn = await sql.connect(config)

// query
let result = await sql.query(query)

// close connection
await cnn.close()
```

Comment: What if we don't close the connection? Will it kill itself after a timeout?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because promises are asynchronous, which happens then when `console.log(theList);` is executed the query to the database is still in process therefore theList prints undefined because no value has been assigned to it.

Following your code and if your version of Node.js is 7.6.0 or higher you can do this:

```
const sql = require('mssql');
var dbConfig = {
    server: 'theServer',
    database: 'theDB',
    user: 'un',
    password: 'pw',
    port: 1433
};

let theList;

function executeQuery() {
    return sql.connect(dbConfig).then(pool => {
        // Query     
        return pool.request()
            .query('select top 10 * from THE_TABLE')
    }).then(result => {
        theList = result;
    }).catch(err => {
        // ... error checks
    })
}

async function getData() {
    await executeQuery();
    console.log(theList);
}

getData();
```

Answer (score -4):

you should call

```
process.exit()
```

in the end. Source [Node Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code)

Moreover

```
sql.connect(dbConfig).then(pool => {
    // Query     
    return pool.request()
    .query('select top 10 * from THE_TABLE')
}).then(result => {
    theList= result;
}).catch(err => {
    // ... error checks
})
```

is an async function

```
console.log(theList);
```

would not wait for it to update the value.

I think you want to do

```
sql.connect(dbConfig).then(pool => {
    // Query     
    return pool.request()
    .query('select top 10 * from THE_TABLE')
}).then(result => {
    theList= result;
}).catch(err => {
    // ... error checks
}).then(function(){
  console.log(theList);
  process.exit(1);
})
```

Comment: That exits the process, but does not get me my variable full of results. This seems like it would be a dirty way to just stop node.js. Is that correct? The link says this: `It is important to note that calling process.exit() will force the process to exit as quickly as possible even if there are still asynchronous operations pending...`  That is not what I am asking for.

Comment: you can add process.exit() in a final then(). which would wait for all your async operations and then exit the process

Comment: How do I get it to wait for the results of this query before moving on? I think I am completely misundertanding this, and possibly using the wrong solution. All I want is to send a query, get the results, and then continue doing other things.

Comment: Ok, you got the part why you weren't printing anything in the consol.log() right ?

Comment: Now since this function is async, and is using promises you would have to chain your other stuff with this if you want it to happen in a sequential manner

Comment: I dont necessarily care about using promises. This was the first example from that page I could get working. I dont really care about any dependencies, or timing or anything else. Maybe I should open a new question, because all I really want is a simple function to query a DB and spit back the results.

Comment: try the last code sample in my answer without process.exit(). that would print the result