# Node.js mssql close open connection

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I am building an API integration application in Node.js using the "mssql" package. I have the data pulling from the third-party API, and stored in my SQL Server. However, my DB connection stays open forever and keeps my app running. Everything that I have tried ends the connection before the data can be stored. So, I can either store my data and keep the connection open forever, or end my connection and not store the data. The best that I have found is something like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45681751/5552707.

And I have tried that in my app, which still kills my connection before data is stored:

```
sql.connect(sqlConfig).then(pool => {

    var request = new sql.Request(pool);
    var result = request.bulk(table, (err, result) => {

        if(err){
            console.log("fail. " + err);
            return;
        }

    })

}).catch(err => {
    console.log('There was an error processing the request. ' + err);
}).then(() => {
    console.log('done');
    process.exit(1);
});
```

They docs don't explain how to do this, which is frustrating.

Any ideas would be awesome!

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding

```
process.exit();
```

to the callback function did the trick.

```
var request = new sql.Request(pool);
var result = request.bulk(table, (err) => {

    if(err){
        console.log("fail. " + err);
        return;
    }

    process.exit(1);
        
})
```